# Control.ModifierKeys doesn't fire on Return/Enter key

Tags: c#, winforms, key, detect

I'm trying to detect when the user presses the Return key while in a Winforms textbox, but neither control statement below works *when I use Keys.Enter and/or Keys.Return*. It does work when I detect other keys such as Alt and Shift. What am I missing? They only vague lead that I have is that I'm testing this on a MacBook keyboard (running Windows), but surely those keys are mapped 100% correctly?

```
private void txtInput_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Enter))
    {
        btnOK_Click(null, null);
    }

    if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Return) != 0)
    {
        btnOK_Click(null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Enter is not a modifier key...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter
```

`Control.ModifierKeys` catch only if ctrl,alt,shift are pressed!

if you need catch only 'enter' pressed w/o any key pressed  use:

```
e.KeyData == Keys.Enter
```

Comment: Should be e.KeyData, you typically don't want to do this when a modifier is down (i.e. Alt+Enter).

Comment: @Hans: typically I use it in keypress event. Is not clear what OP really want to catch